# Error reporting in a C library

Tags: c, design-patterns, error-reporting

I am looking for a robust way to report errors in a C library. Consider the simple example of a queue:

```
struct queue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
if (NULL == q) {
    /* malloc failed. now what ? */
    return NULL; /* maybe ? */
}
```

Okay, so for that example returning `NULL` isn't otherwise valid so it makes sense to return it to signal an error. But

```
void *get_data()
{
    /* stuff */

    /* Error detected. NULL is a valid return, now what ? */

    /* stuff */
}
```

What's more, once we signal an error, how to signal *what* is the error ? I have thought about it and don't have a satisfying solution.

- Using `errno` or some other global object isn't
  something I would like to do (perhaps
  the functions may be called from
  multiple threads etc).
- I thought of making the client supply
  some "status" object that can be
  inspected after the call, but that
  would make the API quite ugly.

So what's your take on the subject ? How do you report errors in a clean way ?

Comment: Another option is to make the return value have different meanings (or be just the return status) and pass objects (pointers) in parameters ... like, for example, `system` does

Comment: @pmg That too is a sensible approach.

Comment: Honestly, I'm about to just make a  error code bitmask and put all of the error fields for my bit reading/writing/etc in it's own struct that I check everytime it's ran.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int get_data(void **ptr)
```

If there are no obvious 'error returns', then maybe your output value should not be the return value. The error could either be an errno, some other custom detailed error value (*cough* HRESULT), just true/false for if the function succeeded, or some other bit of useful information (the length of the data, or -1 if error)

Answer (score 6):

I have a couple of suggestions.

**Suggestion #1** -- Use custom errnos.
I know that you indicated that you would prefer not to use that.  I gather that you are concerned that errno will be clobbered in a multi-threaded environment, but I would expect that each thread should have its own storage for errno.  The following link http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?errno+3 suggests that it is rather easy to do.

As far as structuring the custom errno's, you can always divide the errno up into two portions ... a module number and an module error code.

```
eg.
#define MODULE_NAME_error_code ((MODULE_NUMBER << 16) | (error_code))
```

In case of detected errors in your library, you can then set the errno to a desired value.  If there are multiple modules, it can help identify the problem area.  Of course, if your library is to be used with others that use this method, then some form of synchronization of custom errno's is required.

**Suggestion #2** -- Let your routines return 0 on success with a custom non-zero value on return and let one of the parameters be a pointer to the value you want to set.  Errors can be detected easily; however documenting them may be troublesome if you have deep call trees that use this methodology.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want a multithreaded, reentrant, way to report errors, I think you cannot escape, in every lib call, to pass a pointer to a "status" struct . That struct would have among other object state stuff, the result of the call in question.

It's ugly indeed, but not necessarily bad.

Comment: You can achieve this in a less ugly way by using thread-local storage to maintain the error struct and having functions report only whether an error occurs. So, for example, `void foo(int bar, int biz, struct my_error_t *e);` becomes `int foo(int bar, int biz);`, like a normal function, where, say, a nonzero return value signifies an error. When an error occurs, `foo` calls `set_my_error` to modify the thread-local error context. Similarly, `foo`'s caller may call `get_my_error` to retrieve detailed error information, if it so desires.

Answer (score 3):

Having a "status" argument passed as a pointer may seem a bit ugly, but is accepted in C programming since higher-level error reporting facilities do not exist in the language.

Each bit in the status variable would represent a different error, so if `NULL` is returned, the caller will have to test whether `status & ERR_NOMEM` or `status & ERR_IO`, etc. The error masks can be defined as follows:

```
#define ERR_NOMEM (1 << 0)
#define ERR_IO    (1 << 1)
...
```

Setting the appropriate error inside the functions could be done as `status |= ERR_IO`.

This even gives you the flexibility to indicate more than one error sometimes - the caller can check `status & (ERR_NOMEM | ERR_IO)` to test whether any of the errors have occurred.

Comment: If you are going to pass a parameter anyway, why not pass a pointer to a struct? That way you can completely change (and decide even if you wanna keep binary compatibility) how stuff works and have interfaces like: `mylib_fancy_error_msg(&mylib_state)`.

Answer (score -4):

My first thought: why not use stderr, filling it with messages indicating source and cause of the problem? Or, maybe I missed your intention :)

Comment: 1. Because I would pollute the `stderr` of the client. 2. Because `stderr` might not even be available (GUI app?) 3. Because the client would have to parse strings to find the error (and I would later be unable to change those strings without breaking programs).

Comment: OK. I know what you're up to, but for the sake of response :) - 1. It could be easily filtered if you'd include some textual prefix like "MyLib: ". 2. If you'll use simple fprintf, you'll be able to change output stream to your heart's content. Besides, I think stderr availability doesn't have to do with GUI programs. 3. This one is true for whatever way of error reporting you decide. Regardless of the former, other solution would be to return from function struct with detailed error description(s). I'd go for that since it doesn't require you to use unelegant global variables.

Comment: Well, (2): perhaps the client doesn't want to have to do I/O to get an error. And (3): if I use integer codes the client won't have to parse anything.

Comment: 2. Yup… possible :), 3. I meant that you would be unable to change specific error "codes" without breaking existing dependent programs. But… how about returning struct? There would have to be some memory management involved but it'd be most flexible solution IMHO?